# SQL LIKE condition to check for integer?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a set of SQL LIKE conditions to go through the alphabet and list all items beginning with the appropriate letter, e.g. to get all books where the title starts with the letter "A":

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE title ILIKE "A%"
```

That's fine for letters, but how do I list all items starting with any number?  For what it's worth this is on a Postgres DB.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

That will select (by a regex) every book which has a title starting with a number, is that what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE title ~ '^[0-9]'
```

if you want integers which start with specific digits, you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE CAST(price AS TEXT) LIKE '123%'
```

or use (if all your numbers have the same number of digits (a constraint would be useful then))

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE price BETWEEN 123000 AND 123999;
```

Comment: When trying op2 I get "Explicit conversion from data type int to text is not allowed."

Comment: If option 2 returns the explicit conversion error mentioned in the comment above (which may happen in SQL Server and perhaps other programs), try using VARCHAR with a large enough max size: SELECT * FROM books WHERE CAST(price AS VARCHAR(20)) LIKE '%123%'

Comment: Thank you very much! I can add 5 penny: you can also use: [...] CAST(price AS TEXT) ~*  '123%'   using operator ~*. Also you can use any regexps inside then, like:  [...] CAST(price AS TEXT) ~*  '^123\-?456$'

Answer (score 24):

PostgreSQL supports [regular expressions matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE).

So, your example would look like

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE title ~ '^\d+ ?'
```

This will match a title starting with one or more digits and an optional space

Answer (score 18):

If you want to search as string, you can cast to text like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE price::TEXT LIKE '123%'
```

Answer (score 6):

Tested on PostgreSQL 9.5 :

-- only digits

```
select * from books where title ~ '^[0-9]*$';
```

or,

```
select * from books where title SIMILAR TO '[0-9]*';
```

-- start with digit

```
select * from books where title ~ '^[0-9]+';
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're looking for "numbers that start with 7" rather than "strings that start with 7," maybe something like

```
select * from books where convert(char(32), book_id) like '7%'
```

Or whatever the Postgres equivalent of convert is.

Answer (score 1):

Which one of those is indexable?

This one is definitely btree-indexable:

```
WHERE title >= '0' AND title < ':'
```

Note that ':' comes after '9' in ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party here, but if you're dealing with integers of a fixed length you can just do integer comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE price > 89999 AND price < 90100;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostreSQL you can use **SIMILAR TO** operator ([more](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html)):

```
-- only digits
select * from books where title similar to '^[0-9]*$';
-- start with digit
select * from books where title similar to '^[0-9]%$';
```

Comment: only digits: where title ~ '^[0-9]*$';

Comment: Seems SIMILAR TO is not working with "^" in PostgreSQL 9.5; 
POSIX Regular Expressions "~" works.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to find all values that contain a number (regardless of its position) you can just use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM books WHERE title ~ '[0-9]'
```

(tested with PostgreSQL 13.4)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `like` for int column, use `CAST` to varchar.
 (This is Objection RawFunction query example)

```
.where(
      db.obj.raw("CAST(id AS varchar)"),
      "like",
      `%${data.id}%`
    )
```