# How to search by last ID characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm developing with Rails 2.3.8 and PostgreSQL 9.0.
I want to search by some last characters in ID.

When I post id '123' and return records which last 3 character contains '123', like '100123', '200123', '300123' and so on.

How to search records by last characters in ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE CAST(id AS TEXT) LIKE '%123'
```

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684291/sql-like-condition-to-check-for-integer)