# How to add the parameter with Like operator in Stored Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-like

How to add the `@id` parameter with `Like` operator after `+` sign in Stored Procedure?

My Query:

```
create procedure gen_report_sp(@id int)
as begin
insert into report select * from cache where id like (@id+’%’)
end
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a "%" to an integer - is this what you want to do?

If so, you would need to cast your integer to varchar (or similar) - see this article: [SQL LIKE condition to check for integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684291/sql-like-condition-to-check-for-integer)

Failing that, you should rethink what the process is doing and maybe use 
    `id >= @id` depending on what you actually want to do.