# Like query on Integer primary key Id

Tags: sql, elixir, sql-like, ecto

In ecto I can write

```
query = from q in CustomerModel, where: like(q.id, "%1")
#Ecto.Query<from c in Qber.V1.CustomerModel, where: like(c.id, "%1")>
```

and when I run this query I get

```
(undefined_function): operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown
```

from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684291/sql-like-condition-to-check-for-integer) I got the idea that I have to **Cast** before applying **Like** on **ID**. So in **Postgres**, I can simply write this query as

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CAST(id AS TEXT) LIKE '1%';
```

How do I apply cast in ecto before apply **Like?**

Comment: I have also been going through ecto docs but couldn't find something which solves this

Comment: Why are you trying to do like on an id column? Its value represents nothing meaningful. (Hint: Modulo 10.)

Comment: @jarlh its a requirement but I agree to your point that in most of the cases its not meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fragment` to create a query identical to what you want:

```
query =
  from q in CustomerModel,
    where: like(fragment("CAST(? AS TEXT)", q.id), "1%")
```

Comment: Thank you. thats exactly I was looking for. It worked

Comment: I was writing it down, but @Dogber is always faster :)