# rails/PostgreSQL query which contains the search string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, integer, find-in-set

I am using ror framework to generate a rest api with PostgreSQl as a database. I have a table with the following structure:
orders
id: uuid
code: int8

Rows:
1 1000000045

So, the above row should be selected when the user types in either 45 or 4. How can I do that ?
The ror code that I am trying with is as below:

```
scope :by_code_number, lambda { |code_number|
    where(code_number: code_number)
}
```

How can we achieve this using ror with postgresql. Is this possible with int8 datatype for the column or is only possible with String datatype.

Thanks

Comment: it's only possible with strings, but you can cast your int8 to a string and then use LIKE to search for it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684312/4473406

Comment: Fastest way, use PgSearch https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search ; it will take care of all of these issues